# Why isn't there a typescript error when omitting a non-optional function argument?

Tags: typescript

The following assignment won't error:

```
const foo: (time: number) => void = () => {};
```

... but it will error if, say:

```
const foo: (time: number) => void = (x: string) => {};
```

I'm surprised by this - I'd want and expect TS to error if I'm not passing/assigning the exact function.

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters